# defining a lambda function with two arguments

Tags: python

I have some code as shown below.

```
import math
square_root = lambda x: math.sqrt(x)
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
map(square_root,list)
```

Output:

```
[1.0,
 1.4142135623730951,
 1.7320508075688772,
 2.0,
 2.23606797749979,
 2.449489742783178,
 2.6457513110645907,
 2.8284271247461903,
 3.0,
 3.1622776601683795,
 3.3166247903554,
 3.4641016151377544,
 3.605551275463989,
 3.7416573867739413,
 3.872983346207417,
 4.0]
```

Now I want to use power instead of square_root

```
import math
power = lambda x: math.power(x,n)
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
map(power,list,2)
```

### And I get the following error? How do I use two arguments with map?

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/AD/karthik.sharma/ws_karthik/trunk/ in ()
----> 1 map(power,list,2)

TypeError: argument 3 to map() must support iteration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is the following:

```
power = lambda x, n: math.pow(x,n)
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
map(power,list,[2]*len(list))
```

The expression `[2]*len(list)` creates another list the same length as your existing one, where each element contains the value 2. The `map` function takes an element from each of its input lists and applies that to your `power` function.

Another way is:

```
power = lambda x, n: math.pow(x,n)
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
map(lambda x: power(x, 2),list)
```

which uses partial application to create a second lambda function that takes only one argument and raises it to the power 2.

Note that you should avoid using the name `list` as a variable because it is the name of the built-in Python `list` type.

Comment: You could also use `map(power, list, itertools.repeat(2, len(list)))` to avoid creating a second list.

Comment: If you wanted to be ultra-fancy, you could use `itertools.cycle([2])` instead of `[2]*len(list)`.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
power = lambda x, n: math.pow(x,n)
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
map(lambda x: power(x, 2), list)
```

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions are another option:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
[math.pow(x,2) for x in list]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
power = lambda n: lambda x: math.pow(x,n)
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
map(power(2),list)
```